# String Array that contains String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, contains

Hello and sorry for the noobish question. I have done a lot of search about my problem but i found nothing related to my problem.

So i have something like this:

```
public static String something [][] = 
{
    {"1","100"},
    {"2","1000"},
    {"3","10000"}
};

public static String somethingelse [][] = 
{
    {"1","100"},
    {"2","1000"},
    {"3","10000"}
};

public static String CATEGORIES[][][] = 
{
    something,
    somethingelse
};
```

How and if it is possible ofcourse can i return from the CATEGORIES[something].get(1st line) line?

I dont want to use something[0]
I want to use something like this CATEGORIES.something[0]
i dont know how else to explain it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you tag the language, you might get help a little quicker.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the language is Java

Comment: Define a class with two fields: something and somethingElse. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Answer (score 1):

You can (but it is an awful practice) with this:

```
public static class Categories {
    public String something [][] = {
        {"1","100"},
        {"2","1000"},
        {"3","10000"}
    };

    public String somethingelse [][] = {
        {"1","100"},
        {"2","1000"},
        {"3","10000"}
    };
}

public static final Categories CATEGORIES = new Categories();
```

Comment: You create a new instance from a static class?

Comment: What is awful is to make the fields public, not to create a class with fields holding state. The class itself could be private to make is less awful.

Comment: @Bálint are you thinking in  `abstract` class? It's a public nested static class. Of course you can create a new instance.

Comment: @JBNizet can you call `CATEGORIES.something[0]`  in other class?

Comment: No, you can't. I made the incorrect assumption that the constant was private.

Comment: Thanks for the response but how exactly i can take the 1line from something and put it in a variable in another class?

Comment: @HellDev first, you must to know the difference between a variable value and a variable name. do you want take (and remove) a line from something? Collections are better for this things (List of lines, Map of categories) @ Bálint response is a good example.

Comment: I will check what you wrote and see if it fits to my needs. I will comment if i have any question. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a HashMap with the key-value pairs as the name of the list and an arraylist like this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> c = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
s.put("HI");
s.put("HELLO");
ArrayList<String> s2 = nee ArrayList<>();
s2.put("HI Again!");
s2.put("Hello Again");
c.put("something", s);
c.put("something2", s2);
```

Then you can access them as

```
c.get("something").get(0);
```

Note: Sorry for the inconvenient variable names, I'm on a phone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it looks a bit confusing

Comment: @HellDev check out oracle's tutorial on collections https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation mate i will check your code tommorow to see if it does what i want and will reply you. Thanks again!